# PrincipalPermission only works with some AD groups

Tags: c#, wcf, active-directory, iis-7.5, principalpermission

The following works perfectly (`DOMAIN\DEVELOPERS`):

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,Role="DEVELOPERS")]
public string Test()
{
   return "Works..";
}
```

The user that runs is a member of this group, so "of course" it works. I have another group, for this WCF service that is named `AdvisoryWcfUsers`, which contains a couple of users as well as groups (in the AD; so `DOMAIN\AdvisoryWcfUsers`). I'm 100 percent sure I'm a member of this group, but nevertheless, I get:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: Access is denied

It's not a typo, it just seems that the IIS doesn't have permission to look up this new group. The `DEVELOPERS` group is an "old" group, while the `AdvisoryWcfUsers` was created today, for this purpose. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you log in again after the group was created and you were made a member of it? Windows groups are so called "subauthorities" that are attached to your security token at login. Any change of group memberships is therefore only detected after a login (must be a domain login, not a cached one!).